# Check if certificate with specific serial no. exist in Firefox cert db

Tags: firefox, certificate, nss, certutil

How can I check if a certificate with a specific serial number already exist in a cert db of a Firefox user profile?

I've so far been using the command below to check it and then parse the output:

```
certutil.exe -L -d C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>
```

This is working fine when working with just 1 certificate, but I now need to check multiple certificates where 2 of them unfortunately share the same "Certificate Nickname".

Can I somehow either get the serial number of all installed certificates or query if a certificate with a specified serial number is installed?

I'm using certutil.exe built from nss-3.16.1-with-nspr-4.10.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `certutil` lets you do this, however, doing something like this in `nss` itself is easy enough.

Here is a Python example using `python-nss` which just dumps all serial numbers and nicknames from a db.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from nss import nss

nss.nss_init(sys.argv[1])
for cert in nss.list_certs(nss.PK11CertListAll):
    try:
        print("{} {}".format(cert.serial_number, cert.make_ca_nickname()))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex, file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Is this something that can be used in or ported to a Windows environment?